# Java JTable overlapping table after second buttonclick

Tags: java, swing, model, jtable

When i clicked to button, everything is fine.
But if i select another date and click to button again, table is overlapping and so weird.

Where is my mistake? My button's action codes is here:

```js
btnBilgileriGetir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
  try {
   Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
   Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://xxxx.com:3306/xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx");
   
   Date chosenDate = new Date();
   chosenDate = dateChooser.getDate();
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
   String tarih=sdf.format(chosenDate);
   
   String query = "SELECT * FROM `dailyData` WHERE tarih='" + tarih + "' ORDER BY `number`";
   Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
   ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
   
   contentPane.add(table);
   JScrollPane scrollTable;
   scrollTable = new JScrollPane(table);
   scrollTable.setBounds(72, 95, 1236, 513);
   scrollTable.setVisible(true);
   getContentPane().add(scrollTable);
   
   if(model.getColumnCount() == 0)
   {
    model.addColumn("Tarih");
    model.addColumn("Numara");
    model.addColumn("Litre");
   }   
   
   while(rs.next())
   {
    String sTarih = String.valueOf(rs.getDate(1));
    String sNumara = String.valueOf(rs.getInt(2));
    String sLitre = String.valueOf(rs.getDouble(3));    
    
    model.addRow(new Object[]{sTarih, sNumara, sLitre});
   }

   
   table.setModel(model);
   model.fireTableDataChanged();      
   
  } catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println(e);
  }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> . But if i select another date and click to button again, table is overlapping and so weird.

```
getContentPane().add(scrollTable);
```

Don't keep creating and adding new components to the frame. The old component is never removed so you have multiple components in the frame at the same location.

You should be adding your components to the frame once in the constructor of your class.

Then to change the data you have to options.

1. the best is to just change the model of the table by using the setModel(...) method of the `Table`
2. the other option is to change the component in the viewport of the scrollpane. This is done by using the `setViewportView(...)` method of the `JScrollPane`. So you create a new JTable and add it to the viewport.

So your `ActionListener` logic will now just create either a `TableModel` or a `TableModel` and a `JTable`, depending on which approach you use. The first approach is easier as you only create a single new object.